# The item, that has direction?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to give English name for the class of items at the traffic schema (it's about software).

There are several classes of items. For some of them user *can* set direction (forward/backward). It's something like "this road can be used for moving forward only, and that - for moving backward" (or escalators, which can move up or down only at the same time).

How would you name these items?

Comment: Are you asking  for a single word which means "direction can be set" like *directable,* perhaps?

Comment: @AndrewLeach: exactly. I've thought about "directable" (like "editable", "observable"), but I'm not sure, that it could be used...

Comment: Maybe you could work with orientation, by calling them orientable objects.

Comment: @Neptunian: since this is schema (that is, some drawing with shapes), orientation is already reserved and used as "vertical" and "horizontal" (layout relative to schema dimensions).

Comment: Some more clarification in your question, based on your responses to answers and comments, should be considered.

Comment: Not strictly english, but in studying physics and geometry you often encounter the word 'vector' used to represent physical quantities that have both magnitude and direction.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that an object which can have a direction associated with it **has directionality**; from [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/directionality):

> of, relating to, or indicating direction in space

Hence a road has directionality, and that direction can be forwards, backwards or both.

So for an item I can see two options:

1. You could have a field "Has directionality?" with either a true or false. If "true" then another field "Direction" becomes available where you can state what direction it has.
2. You have a field called "Direction" with options {None; Forward; Backwards; Both}

Comment: The problem isn't in how I can name field, this is trivial. The problem is to give a common name for objects, that can have direction. Like this: "all items, that could be edited, are editable". So, "all items, that could have direction, are... ?".

Comment: @Dennis - Understood. My suggestion was to use "have directionality". I couldn't come up with an adjective form.